# scan string using nsscanner class

Tags: objective-c

I want to scan this string

```
"hello I am emp 1313 object of string class 123"
```

so in this I want to know if their are any integer value present and if present I want to display them for this I am using the NSScanner class and heres a view of my code

```
NSString *str = @" hello I am emp 1313 object of string class 123";

NSString *limit = @" object";
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];

int i;
[scanner scanInt:&i];
NSString *output;
[scanner scanUpToString:limit intoString:&output];
NSLog(@"%d",i);
```

but the problem is that I am not able to do it and I want to use NSScanner class only so can you experts give me some suggesstions regarding this.....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
NSString *str = @" hello i am emp 1313 object of string class 123";
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];

// set it to skip non-numeric characters
[scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]];

int i;
while ([scanner scanInt:&i])
{
    NSLog(@"Found int: %d",i);
}

// reset the scanner to skip numeric characters
[scanner setScanLocation:0];
[scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]];

NSString *resultString;
while ([scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] intoString:&resultString]) {
    NSLog(@"Found string: %@",resultString);
}
```

It outputs:

```
2010-10-27 14:40:39.137 so[2482:a0f] Found int: 1313
2010-10-27 14:40:39.140 so[2482:a0f] Found int: 123
2010-10-27 14:40:39.141 so[2482:a0f] Found string:  hello i am emp 
2010-10-27 14:40:39.141 so[2482:a0f] Found string:  object of string class
```

Comment: and can u also tell me how to find strings only

Comment: am trying to do the same by this piece of line  [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:[[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]invertedSet]];

Comment: i've updated the answer to include scanning for strings. invertedSet basically says "all characters *except* these ones"